# jquery dectects div element visibility as true even though not visible

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple form and I have jquery code that determines if a div element with id="placeholder" is visible. If it is visible then show an alert box with an error message if not then show an alert box with an ok message.  The problem is that when I click on the submit button, it shows the error message in the alert box instead of the OK alert message.  What's puzzling is that it still shows the error alter box even though the div element does not have innerHTML text. What can be wrong with the code?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Your Information:</legend>
    First name:
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="firstname">
    <br>Last name:
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="lastname">
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="dopost()">
  </fieldset>
</form>

<div id="placeholder"></div>

<script>
  function dopost() {

    if ($('#placeholder').is(':visible')) {

      alert('Found errors in the form, please correct them!');

    } else {

      alert('no errors');

    }

  }
</script>
```

Comment: But your div `placeholder` is visible..... you just can't see it because it's empty.

Comment: @NewToJS I think that is where I'm misunderstanding. Let's say the text "there were errors in the form" is showed dynamically on the webpage when I click the submit button. how do I determine if it is visible on the webpage with jquery?

Comment: It sounds like you don't quite understand what the `:visible` selector does. If you read the jQuery docs, you'll understand why your code doesn't work. Even if the div is empty, it's still visible. Perhaps you want to try `:empty` instead.

Comment: I agree with ChristianVarga, checking the div is empty might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Your Information:</legend>
    First name:
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="firstname">
    <br>Last name:
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="lastname">
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="dopost()">
  </fieldset>
</form>

<div id="placeholder" style="visibility:hidden;"></div>

<script>
  function dopost() {
     
    if ($('#placeholder').attr('visibility')=='visible') {

      alert('Found errors in the form, please correct them!');

    } else {

      alert('no errors');

    }

  }
</script>
```

Comment: The `:visible` psedoselector works with the `visibility` property. There is no need to change the javascript condition; `$('#placeholder').is(':visible')` would return the correct result if the element had `visibility: hidden`